# Is it possible to change the shape of the `UISlider`?

Tags: ios, uislider, uicontrol

Im trying to implement a custom control. Im looking to develop a custom where it is an `7` shape, and and the `handle` starts in the vertical position, at the top of the `7`. Is it possible to override the `drawRect` of UISlider or is it easier to create a completely custom `UIControl`? The desired effect is to have all the same functionality of the UISlider but just a different shape. I dont have much experience with making custom objects so any tips or direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create a custom control.

Comment: Agreed. Trying to make a `UISlider` behave like this will be a LOT more work than building your own control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother subclassing UISlider.  I'd start by recreating UISlider so you can get the hang of creating custom controls, and then I'd switch to your custom shape after you've managed to create a functioning slider.